# How to configure provider level attributes using the Terraform provider framework

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I wanted to implement a provider level configuration functionality so that I can pass an optional  specific ARN for the provider to use in special cases.

for eg.

```
provider "custom_provider" {
     arn = "arn:aws:service:region-1:123456789012"
}
```

I created providers Schema.

```
func (p *customProvider) Schema(_ context.Context, _ provider.SchemaRequest, resp *provider.SchemaResponse) {
    resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
        Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
            "arn": schema.StringAttribute{
                Optional: true,
        },
    }
}
```

and implement provider data model

```
type customProviderModel struct {
    Arn     types.String `tfsdk:"arn"`
}
```

Implement configuration functionality

```
func (p *customProvider) Configure(ctx context.Context, req provider.ConfigureRequest, resp *provider.ConfigureResponse) {
    var config customProviderModel
    var arn string    

    diags := req.Config.Get(ctx, &config)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    if !config.Arn.IsNull() {
        arn = config.Arn.ValueString()
    }
```

but I don't know how to pass the arn to *Data Source* from the configuration so that I can use the arn to assume a role while I'm doing a *Read* functionality inside the *Data source*.

Basically I wanted to have something similar to aws provider where we can pass the region on some special cases.

```
provider "aws" {
     region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: You need a `struct` initialized in the provider initialization function that can be utilized by data sources and resources. This `struct` is typically the "client" (different meanings for that based on the platform API), but further information would be required to be more specific. You would also typically expect its functionality to be defined in the associated Go bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resp *provider.ConfigureResponse` argument to your `Configure` implementation is a [`ConfigureResponse`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v1.2.0/provider#ConfigureResponse) object that you need to populate in your function.

The `DataSourceData` and `ResourceData` fields both accept an object of any type, and the framework will store those two values and then pass them verbatim to the `Configure` methods of your `DataSource` or `Resource` implementations.

To recieve those values your `DataSource` and `Resource` objects must implement [`DataSourceWithConfigure`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v1.2.0/datasource#DataSourceWithConfigure) or [`ResourceWithConfigure`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v1.2.0/resource#ResourceWithConfigure) respectively. The `ConfigureRequest` objects passed to each of those includes the same data object you returned in `DataSourceData` or `ResourceData`.

You can use this mechanism to save whatever information your data source and resource type implementations will need from the provider configuration. A typical design is for the provider-level `Configure` to return a pre-configured client for whatever client library you are using to interact with the real remote system, and then the data source and resource type implementations will make their requests using that client.